# custom faces for font lock keywords per buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

In my `.emacs` I have the following code that highlights tabs and trailing spaces

```
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq font-lock-keywords
      (append font-lock-keywords
        '(("\t+" (0 'custom-tab-face t))
          ("[ \t]+$" (0 'custom-tab-face t)))))))

(custom-set-faces
  '(custom-tab-face ((((class color)) (:background "#a0a0a0"))) t))
```

The above is a global setting.

I am trying to figure out how to disable highlighting (I make it white) in just one buffer that uses a specific programming mode (golang). I tried the code below but it, of course, disables it for all buffers:

```
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (custom-set-faces
      '(custom-tab-face ((((class color)) (:background "#ffffff"))) t))))
```

Please help, I do not know emacs very well.

Comment: On a side note, certain things like tabs can be highlighted with the `display-table`, which will not cause any slowdown in large buffers.  I do this with tabs and spaces, and in some buffers hard return.  font-lock of tabs should work fine in small buffers.  You probably do not want a font-lock-mode-hook, but instead use major-mode hooks.  For buffer-local stuff, perhaps do a Google search for `(setq-local face-remapping-alist. . . `

Comment: thanks. would you be able to post examples of how I would use `display-table` for this?

Comment: I've posted a `display-table` example of tabs, spaces, new-lines, and form-feed.  Trailing spaces will probably require font-lock.  If you haven't already looked at the built-in library of `whitespace.el`, that might be right up your alley.  That library, however, is missing things like colored spaces using the `display-table` and also form-feed -- instead, it uses font-lock for spaces (which causes a slow-down in large buffers for colored spaces).

Comment: The following example uses one character space for tabs, but you can change the number 1 to anything you want -- e.g., 2 or 4 or 8, etc.:  `(defun my-tab-function () (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 1 200 1)) (setq tab-width 1) (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)) (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-tab-function)`  NOTE:  Many popular major modes have their own set tab-width -- e.g., 8.

Comment: I have a `tab-width` set in my hook, but as far as I understand the problem is that `display-table` replaces tabs with the defined glyphs so `tab-width` does not have any effect, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you may be right -- I haven't used tab-with greater than 1 for the past few months.  `whitespace-mode.el` has the feature you seek built-in for tabs.  I'll need to spend some time looking at `whitespace-mode.el` to see the magic ingredient -- I may not be able to locate it tonight, but will check back again tomorrow.  In the meantime, try `M-x whitespace-mode`.

Comment: I figured it out: `(aset buffer-display-table ?\t (vector glyph-tab glyph-tab))`

Comment: Yes, me too -- I needed an extra `?\t` -- I've updated the answer with an example using 8 for the tab-width.

Comment: There is no need to highlight end-of-line whitespace using font-lock. You can use the build it feature `show-trailing-whitespace` which use the face `trailing-whitespace`. As a bonus, it doesn't highlight trailing whitespace when the cursor is at the end of the line, reducing annoying flickering when typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the request of the original poster, here is an example using the `display-table`, which works well in large buffers and does not cause a slow down that would ordinarily be experienced with font-lock.  I've attached the function to a `text-mode-hook` -- the major-mode hook can be changed to suit the needs of the original poster.

```lisp
(defgroup example nil
  "Faces for highlighting display table entries."
  :group 'example)

(defface ws-formfeed-face
  '((t (:background "purple" :foreground "yellow" :weight bold)))
  "Face for `ws-formfeed-face`."
  :group 'example)

(defface ws-newline-face
  '((t (:foreground "blue")))
  "Face for `ws-newline-face`."
  :group 'example)

(defface ws-space-face
  '((t (:foreground "DarkRed")))
  "Face for `ws-space-face`."
  :group 'example)

(defface ws-tab-face
  '((t (:foreground "cyan")))
  "Face for `ws-tab-face`."
  :group 'example)

(defun my-display-table-function ()
  (let* (
       (my-glyph-formfeed (make-glyph-code ?\U0001D4D5 'ws-formfeed-face))
       (my-glyph-pilcrow (make-glyph-code ?\u00B6 'ws-newline-face))
       (my-glyph-space (make-glyph-code ?\u00B7 'ws-space-face))
       (my-glyph-tab
         (cond
           ((eq system-type 'darwin)
             (make-glyph-code ?\u203A 'ws-tab-face))
           ((eq system-type 'windows-nt)
             (make-glyph-code ?\u00BB 'ws-tab-face)))) )
     (when (not buffer-display-table)
       (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table)))
     (aset buffer-display-table ?\n `[,my-glyph-pilcrow ?\n])
     (aset buffer-display-table ?\014 `[,my-glyph-formfeed])
     (aset buffer-display-table ?\ `[,my-glyph-space])
     (aset buffer-display-table ?\t `[,my-glyph-tab ?\t])))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-display-table-function)

(defun my-tab-function ()
  (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 8 200 8))
  (setq tab-width 8)
  (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-tab-function)
```